# How to add control in cell of devexpress spreadsheet?

Tags: devexpress, controls, addition, spreadsheet

How to add control(combobox, checkbox, radio, button ...) in cell of devexpress spreadsheet ?
Thank you !

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WinForms XtraSpreadsheet control - take a look at the [example on the DevExpress site](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T259398). It describes how to display custom controls instead of the standard cell editor.